# Move an element one place up or down in the dom tree with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, move

I want a javascript way to move an element one place up or down in the dom tree within a particular known parent using javascript (or jquery is ok), but i want the script to know when an element is the first or last element within the parent and not be moved. for example, if i have the following ...

```
<div id='parent_div'>
    <div id='div_1'></div>
    <div id='div_2'></div>
    <div id='div_3'></div>
</div>
```

on click of a button, i want to pass a known id (let's say `div_2`) and move it up to the position above it, swapping its position with the element that was previously before it (in this case `div_1`). The ids of the elements don't have to change, and their new position doesn't need to be known, at least not unless they are moved again.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
var e = $("#div_2");
// move up:
e.prev().insertAfter(e);
// move down:
e.next().insertBefore(e);
```

Comment: thanks! i can then use `next()` to move it down, and then `remove()` to remove the old item

Answer (score 62):

Move `element` "up":

```
if(element.previousElementSibling)
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(element, element.previousElementSibling);
```

Move `element` "down":

```
if(element.nextElementSibling)
  element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.nextElementSibling, element);
```

```js
function moveUp(element) {
  if(element.previousElementSibling)
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(element, element.previousElementSibling);
}
function moveDown(element) {
  if(element.nextElementSibling)
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(element.nextElementSibling, element);
}
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.className === 'down') moveDown(e.target.parentNode);
  else if(e.target.className === 'up') moveUp(e.target.parentNode);
});
```

```css
.up, .down        { cursor: pointer; }
.up:after         { content: '△'; }
.up:hover:after   { content: '▲'; }
.down:after       { content: '▽'; }
.down:hover:after { content: '▼'; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1<span class="up"></span><span class="down"></span></li>
  <li>2<span class="up"></span><span class="down"></span></li>
  <li>3<span class="up"></span><span class="down"></span></li>
  <li>4<span class="up"></span><span class="down"></span></li>
  <li>5<span class="up"></span><span class="down"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Plus 1 for vanilla JavaScript

Answer (score 4):

You can use JQuery's built in `.index()` method to get the location of a child element and get the `.length` value form a parent element to find out the number of elements.

If `index` comes back 0, it is the first element, if the `index` comes back parent element length -1 then you know it is the last element.

For moving the elements them self you can use `.insertBefore` and `.prev` to move an element up.

```
    var elm = $("selector_for_the_element");
    elm.insertBefore(elm.prev());
```

For moving an elemetn down then you can use `insertAfter` and `.next`

```
    var elm = $("selector_for_the_element");
    elm.insertAfter(elm.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all the child div with parent div id (#parent_div) using $.each function of jQuery. 
suppose you want to swap div3 with div2, then index of div3 will be 2. use $(#div_3).insertBefore(#div_2)