# Move elements depending on index with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to move my elements (task from todo list) depending on the index. If the index is increasing, then the `div` moves down; if it decreases, then the `div` moves up. I know the functions `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`, but unfortunately, I do not understand how to use them.

```js
var task = [];
function newElement(newChild) {
    let btnDel = document.createElement("button");
    btnDel.className = "fa fa-trash-o";
    let myEd = document.getElementById("myEdit");
    let spanClose1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
    let spanRedact = document.getElementsByClassName("redact")[0];
    let myDel = document.getElementById("myDelete");
    let spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    let spanYes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes")[0];

    // Create button
    let divWithBut = document.createElement("div");
    divWithBut.className = "forButt";
    let btnRedact = document.createElement("button");
    btnRedact.className = "fa fa-pencil";

    // Redact but
    btnRedact.onclick = function() {
        myEd.style.display = "block";
        let editText = document.getElementById("editText");
        let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
        editText.value = divWithText.innerHTML;
        editText.currentTarget;
        spanRedact.onclick = function() {
            divWithText.textContent = editText.value;
            divWithText.className = "todoPost";
            myEd.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanClose1.onclick = function() {
            myEd.style.display = "none";
        };
    }
    /*************************** */

    /* Done but */
    let doneBut = document.createElement("button");
    doneBut.className = "fa fa-check-circle-o";
    doneBut.onclick = function() {
        let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
        divWithText.classList.toggle("checked");
    }

    /******************* */

    divWithBut.appendChild(btnRedact);
    divWithBut.appendChild(doneBut);
    divWithBut.appendChild(btnDel);
    /******************/

    // For index
    let indexDiv = document.createElement("div");
    indexDiv.className = "indexDiv";
    let numbInd = 1;
    indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;

    /*********************************** */

    // Create arrow
    let divWithArrow = document.createElement("div");
    divWithArrow.className = "myArrow";
    let arrowUP = document.createElement("i");
    arrowUP.className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
    let arrowDown = document.createElement("i");
    arrowDown.className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowUP);
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowDown);

    // For date
    let date = new Date();
    let curr_date = date.getDate();
    let curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; // +1 бо почина з 0 і випада місяць на 1 менше
    let curr_year = date.getFullYear();
    let curr_hour = date.getHours();
    let curr_minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let d = (curr_date + "." + curr_month + "." + curr_year + "<br>" +
             curr_hour + ":" + curr_minutes);
    let divTime = document.createElement("div");
    divTime.style.textAlign = "center";;
    divTime.innerHTML = d;

    //***************************/

    let div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "timeComent";
    let myli = document.createElement("li");
    myli.className = "todoPost";
    let addField = document.getElementById("addField").value;
    task = document.createTextNode(addField);
    myli.appendChild(task);
    div1.appendChild(divTime);
    div1.appendChild(indexDiv);
    div1.appendChild(divWithArrow);
    div1.appendChild(myli);
    divWithBut.style.display = "flex";
    div1.appendChild(divWithBut);

    if (addField === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } 
    else {
        task = document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(div1)[0];
    }
    document.getElementById("addField").value = "";

    // Delete but
    btnDel.onclick = function() {
        myDel.style.display = "block";
        spanClose.onclick = function() {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanYes.onclick = function() {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
            div1.remove();
        };
    }

    // Move elements with arrow help
    arrowUP.onclick = function() {
        numbInd = numbInd + 1;
        indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;
        // If I am not mistaken, insertAfter must be here...
    };
    arrowDown.onclick = function() {
        numbInd = numbInd-1;
        indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;
    };
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.firstBar {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.indexDiv {
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #888;
}
.fafaArrow {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
}
.timeComent {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.numberpost {
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(141, 112, 112);
}
.todoPost {
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.shadow {
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.window {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #0000cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #0000cc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
}
.shadow:target {display: block;}


.redact {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.redact:hover {
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;
}
.close {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}
/* Style the close button */
.close3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.yes {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.yes:hover {
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;
}

.close1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close1:hover {
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
div li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
div li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TO DO List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <input id="addField" type="text" size="70%" placeholder="Task" name="Task">
    <button type="button" onclick="newElement()">Add</button>
</header>
<div>
    <div class="firstBar">
        <div class="fafaArrow">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            <input class="inptxt" type="text" size="50%" name="Task">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul id="forToDo">
        <div class="timeComent">
            <div class="myTime"></div>
            <div class="myArrow"></div>
        </div>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="myDelete" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">Delete item?<br>
        <span class="yes">Yes</span>
        <span class="close">No</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myEdit" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">
        Edit text?<br>
        <label>
            <textarea id="editText"></textarea>
        </label>
        <span class="redact">Save</span>
        <span class="close1">Cancel</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an element one place up or down in the dom tree with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913953/move-an-element-one-place-up-or-down-in-the-dom-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: I'd consider something like using the order property of items in a flex container.

Comment: @Dementic Looks like the OP knows how to move the element upwards and downward and can't move it because of the index problem. _I know some function insertBefore and insertAfter, but unfortunately I do not understand how I may use it_

Comment: @weegee not sure, since `insertBefore`/`insertAfter` does not require an index. besides, the answer attached, provides a full solution.

Comment: @Dementic no didn’t mean with an index. I mean that upvote system type the OP created. By taking that, they couldn’t align divs But in general looks like they can by those methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the div with the higher index to go downwards. To do this, you have to select all the divs with the index, obtain the maximum index and append it again to push the div downwards. Do this like

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv'); // get all the index divs
let arr = []; // store the value of indexes in an array
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { // for every .indexDiv
  arr.push(Number(divs[i].innerHTML)) // push the index of the div into the array
}
let maxindex = Math.max.apply(null, arr); // now get the maximum value from array
var found; // your element
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { // for every div again.
  if (divs[i].textContent == maxindex) { // check the index and get that div with max index
    found = divs[i];
    break;
  }
}
if (divs.length > 1) { // check if the number of div's are more than 1.
  found.parentElement.remove() // remove them
  document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(found.parentElement) // then append them to go down
}
```

Do the same for the min value. Just prepend the div this time and make the value mininmum like.

```
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv');
let arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  arr.push(Number(divs[i].innerHTML))
}
let minindex = Math.min.apply(null, arr);

var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv');
var found2;
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
  if (aTags[i].textContent == minindex) {
    found2 = aTags[i];
    break;
  }
}
if (aTags.length > 1) {

  document.getElementById("forToDo").insertBefore(found2.parentElement, document.getElementById("forToDo").firstChild);

}
```

This all, when combined, results in the following, push all this code in the index change event.

```js
var task = [];

function newElement(newChild) {
  let btnDel = document.createElement("button");
  btnDel.className = "fa fa-trash-o";
  let myEd = document.getElementById("myEdit");
  let spanClose1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
  let spanRedact = document.getElementsByClassName("redact")[0];
  let myDel = document.getElementById("myDelete");
  let spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  let spanYes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes")[0];
  //create button
  let divWithBut = document.createElement("div");
  divWithBut.className = "forButt";
  let btnRedact = document.createElement("button");
  btnRedact.className = "fa fa-pencil";
  //redact but
  btnRedact.onclick = function() {
    myEd.style.display = "block";
    let editText = document.getElementById("editText");
    let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
    editText.value = divWithText.innerHTML;
    editText.currentTarget;
    spanRedact.onclick = function() {
      divWithText.textContent = editText.value;
      divWithText.className = "todoPost";
      myEd.style.display = "none";
    };
    spanClose1.onclick = function() {
      myEd.style.display = "none";
    };
  }
  /*************************** */

  /*done but*/
  let doneBut = document.createElement("button");
  doneBut.className = "fa fa-check-circle-o";
  doneBut.onclick = function() {
    let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
    divWithText.classList.toggle("checked");
  }

  /******************* */

  divWithBut.appendChild(btnRedact);
  divWithBut.appendChild(doneBut);
  divWithBut.appendChild(btnDel);
  /******************/

  //for index
  let indexDiv = document.createElement("div");
  indexDiv.className = "indexDiv";
  let numbInd = 1;
  indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;
  /*********************************** */
  //create arrow
  let divWithArrow = document.createElement("div");
  divWithArrow.className = "myArrow";
  let arrowUP = document.createElement("i");
  arrowUP.className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
  let arrowDown = document.createElement("i");
  arrowDown.className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
  divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowUP);
  divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowDown);

  //for date
  let date = new Date();
  let curr_date = date.getDate();
  let curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; //+1 бо почина з 0 і випада місяць на 1 менше
  let curr_year = date.getFullYear();
  let curr_hour = date.getHours();
  let curr_minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let d = (curr_date + "." + curr_month + "." + curr_year + "<br>" + curr_hour + ":" + curr_minutes);
  let divTime = document.createElement("div");
  divTime.style.textAlign = "center";;
  divTime.innerHTML = d;
  //***************************/

  let div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.className = "timeComent";
  let myli = document.createElement("li");
  myli.className = "todoPost";
  let addField = document.getElementById("addField").value;
  task = document.createTextNode(addField);
  myli.appendChild(task);
  div1.appendChild(divTime);
  div1.appendChild(indexDiv);
  div1.appendChild(divWithArrow);
  div1.appendChild(myli);
  divWithBut.style.display = "flex";
  div1.appendChild(divWithBut);

  if (addField === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {

    task = document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(div1)[0];
  }
  document.getElementById("addField").value = "";

  //delete but
  btnDel.onclick = function() {
    myDel.style.display = "block";
    spanClose.onclick = function() {
      myDel.style.display = "none";
    };
    spanYes.onclick = function() {
      myDel.style.display = "none";
      div1.remove();
    };
  }

  //move elements with arrow help
  arrowUP.onclick = function() {
    numbInd = numbInd + 1;
    indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv');
    let arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      arr.push(Number(divs[i].innerHTML))
    }
    let maxindex = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    
 
    var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv');
    var found;
    for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
      if (aTags[i].textContent == maxindex) {
        found = aTags[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (aTags.length > 1) {
      document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(found.parentElement);
    

    }
  };
  arrowDown.onclick = function() {
    numbInd = numbInd - 1;
    indexDiv.innerHTML = numbInd;
    let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv');
    let arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      arr.push(Number(divs[i].innerHTML))
    }
    let minindex = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
    
    var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('.indexDiv');
    var found2;
    for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
      if (aTags[i].textContent == minindex) {
        found2 = aTags[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (aTags.length > 1) {

      document.getElementById("forToDo").insertBefore(found2.parentElement, document.getElementById("forToDo").firstChild);

    }
  };
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.firstBar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.indexDiv {
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #888;
}

.fafaArrow {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
}

.timeComent {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.numberpost {
  padding: 5px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: rgb(141, 112, 112);
}

.todoPost {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.shadow {
  background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.window {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #0000cc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #0000cc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.shadow:target {
  display: block;
}

.redact {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0000cc;
  color: #0000cc;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.redact:hover {
  background-color: #68f462;
  color: white;
}

.close {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0000cc;
  color: #0000cc;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}


/* Style the close button */

.close3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.yes {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0000cc;
  color: #0000cc;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.yes:hover {
  background-color: #68f462;
  color: white;
}

.close1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #0000cc;
  color: #0000cc;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 14pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close1:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}


/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */

div li.checked {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}


/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */

div li.checked::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 15px;
  width: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TO DO List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <input id="addField" type="text" size="70%" placeholder="Task" name="Task">
    <button type="button" onclick="newElement()">Add</button>
  </header>
  <div>
    <div class="firstBar">
      <div class="fafaArrow">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        <input class="inptxt" type="text" size="50%" name="Task">
        <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul id="forToDo">
      <div class="timeComent">
        <div class="myTime"></div>
        <div class="myArrow"></div>
      </div>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div id="myDelete" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">Delete item?<br>
      <span class="yes">Yes</span>
      <span class="close">No</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myEdit" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">
      Edit text?<br>
      <label>
            <textarea id="editText"></textarea>
        </label>
      <span class="redact">Save</span>
      <span class="close1">Cancel</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```